# Exclude project files from rules in Git hook [commit-msg]

Tags: git, hook, commit

I am writing a Git hook in file commit-msg using python.

Purpose is to make sure that commit messages contains the type of work done with code to better manage CI/CD pipelines, like "Debug-activity performed: " 
OR 
"Test-activity performed: "

Now I have to write Debug... OR Test...  in every commit message, when performing 
"git commit -m "Debug... OR Test..."

There are some files in the project like readme.txt that require not to mention Debug OR Test in commit message.

Now i am wondering how can i mention the "readme.txt" file in hook file so that these hook rules ignore that project file, when committing that project file with any other message in "commit - m"

One possible manual way is to use --no-verify with the git command but i am looking for a way to accomplish it through code.

Thanks in advance,
Saqib

Comment: Can you edit the question to format commands appropriately?  Makes it pleasing to read.

Comment: I have edited the post and  now hopefully it's much easier to read and understand.

Comment: I would still insist you format the commands as code.